# mix two array of object and add properties with ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ramda.js

I have two array like below :

```
['TAG.u', 'TAG.c']
```

and another one is :

```
[{name:'some',key:'TAG.u'},
{name:'some new', key: 'TAG.b'}, 
{name:'some another' , key:'TAG.c'},
{name: 'some big' , key:'TAG.a'}]
```

now i want to mix this two array in one array which create new properties `selected: true` for each same key an false for else. like below:

```
resualt : [{name:'some', key: 'TAG.U',selected: true} ,
{name:'some another' , key:'TAG.c' , selcted: true},
{name:'some new', key: 'TAG.b',selected: false},
{name: 'some big' , key:'TAG.a' ,selected: false} ]
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: `[{TAG.u }, {TAG.c}] ` that array syntax is wrong. Is it an array of objects (if so objects need key-value pairs) or is it an array of strings (if so replace curly braces with quotation marks)?

Comment: First array isn't even valid syntax. Provide a [mcve] that doesn't require guessing

Comment: @Ozan question edited.

Comment: @charlietfl question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it like this:

```
const combine = curry((tags, data) => 
  map(d => assoc('selected', contains(d.key, tags), d), data)
)

combine(tags, data)
```

If we tried, I'm sure we could make this point-free, but I don't see a reason to.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20tags%20%3D%20%5B%27TAG.u%27%2C%20%27TAG.c%27%5D%20%0A%0Aconst%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%27some%27%2C%20key%3A%27TAG.u%27%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%27some%20new%27%2C%20key%3A%20%27TAG.b%27%7D%2C%20%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%27some%20another%27%2C%20key%3A%27TAG.c%27%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%27some%20big%27%2C%20key%3A%27TAG.a%27%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20combine%20%3D%20curry%28%28tags%2C%20data%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20map%28d%20%3D%3E%20assoc%28%27selected%27%2C%20contains%28d.key%2C%20tags%29%2C%20d%29%2C%20data%29%0A%29%0A%0Acombine%28tags%2C%20data%29)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate through the second array and look if the `key` values of each object exist in the first array.

```js
var arr1 = ['TAG.u', 'TAG.c'];
var arr2 = [{
    name: 'some',
    key: 'TAG.u'
  },
  {
    name: 'some new',
    key: 'TAG.b'
  },
  {
    name: 'some another',
    key: 'TAG.c'
  },
  {
    name: 'some big',
    key: 'TAG.a'
  }
];

var result = arr2.map(v => {
  v.selected = arr1.indexOf(v.key) > -1;
  return v;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this answer mutates `arr2`. As `arr2'`s items are objects, they're passed by reference in `v =>`. If you're going to do this with vanilla JS one of these would be a better option

`var result = arr2.map(v => ({ ...v, selected: arr1.indexOf(v.key) > -1 }))`

`var result = arr2.map(v => Object.assign({}, v, { selected: arr1.indexOf(v.key) > -1 }))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use ramda's `zipWith` to combine two lists based on the supplied function

```
R.zipWith(
  (item, tag) => R.assoc('selected', item.key === tag, item),
  items,
  tags
 )
```